# android app shortcut to be opened from html link

Tags: javascript, android, html, deep-linking

I can't for the life of me figure this out, please help.
I have a webpage that is required to open an app on the phone if it exists. I can make it work for apps like fb, tiktok, youtube, waze like this:
i can open the fb app with "fb://", tiktok app with: "tiktok://", waze app with: "waze://", youtube app with: "vnd.youtube://" i also need to open glovo app, netflix app. how or where can i find the appropriate short cut for those apps?

the links are added to userData of some 3d objects but that is not really important right now

Comment: I think [this](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-open-an-android-app-from-the-browser/) is what you're searching for.

Comment: I found that article but it's not what i'm searching for. See, i can open the fb app just by adding "fb://" to userData and when the object is clicked it runs "window.open(intersects[0].object.userData);" and it works, it opens the fb app. i want to do that for other apps as well, but i can't seem to find the shortcut that allows me to do that.